# jq returns null when executed from linux commandline

Tags: jq

I have a json text as below

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://xxx:8080/info"
    }
  },
  "build": {
    "name": "xxxx",
    "version": "2.0.23-69",
    "description": "xxxx"
  }
}
```

iam trying to get the version from the above json by using the below command

```
cat info.txt|jq  .version
```

but this is returning null.
how can i get the version as 2.0.23-69

Answer (score 1):

.version is inside .build, so the direct approach would be to write: `.build | .version`, or `.build.version` for short.

If in general you don't know exactly where the object of interest lives, you can also use the `..` filter, e.g. `.. | objects | .version // empty`.